# android getview method error with glide image download

Tags: android, android-glide, getview

I have problem with glide downloading image

erro image view not intilized and c.getPhotourl("")// have error

line where is error:

```
Glide.with(context).load("http://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/cc0000/ffffff"+busViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(c.getPhotourl("")).into(imageView);
```

here is getview method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // View v = convertView;
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        ImageView imageView;

        BusViewHolder busViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test, null);

            txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id1);
            txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            txt3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            busViewHolder = new BusViewHolder(txt1, txt2, txt3);
            convertView.setTag(busViewHolder);
        }
        Contactinfo c = getItem(position);


        busViewHolder = (BusViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        busViewHolder.txt1.setText(c.getGender());
        //  busViewHolder.txt2.setText(""+c.getId());
        busViewHolder.txt3.setText(c.getFirst_name());
        busViewHolder.txt2.setText(c.getId() + "");

        //busViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(c.getPhotourl());

       Glide.with(context).load("http://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/cc0000/ffffff"+busViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(c.getPhotourl("")).into(imageView);
       // String url="https://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/cc0000/ffffff";
        //Glide.with(context).load(url).into(c.getPhotourl(busViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource();));
//


        return convertView;
    }

    class BusViewHolder {
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        ImageView imageView;
        // RatingBar rb;


        public BusViewHolder(TextView txt1, TextView txt2, TextView txt3) {
            this.txt1 = txt1;
            this.txt2 = txt2;
            this.txt3 = txt3;
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Contactinfo getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: busViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(c.getPhotourl("")) which purpose you used this?

Comment: create model using json geter setter  here json link  https://api.myjson.com/bins/1d3ei7

Comment: error here imageview  not intlized     here      into(imageView)

Comment: yes error gone , now  i try and responce

Comment: but one more place getPhotourl("") //what i pass in("") show error

Comment: at the end you want to get image url from model class right?

Comment: model class attribue  private int id;
    private String first_name;
    private String gender;
    private String photourl;     and these getter setter , id,gender,name work well but not in photourl case , you can see in above code for c.getid,c.getgender...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String url="https://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/cc0000/ffffff";
Glide.with(context).load(url).into(busViewHolder.imageView);
//Glide.with(context).load(c.getPhotourl()).into(busViewHolder.imageView); this line get url from model class
```

Comment: error here imageview  not intlized     here      into(imageView)

Comment: use busViewHolder.imageView

Comment: above answer only upload this "https://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/cc0000/ffffff" url image

Comment: yes you right but i want array like json other attribue showing in list id, name , gender all showing in list

Answer (score 0):

You are using ImageView which you declare in getView() but not initialized it.Thats why it return an error imageView is not initialized. Try to use busViewHolder.ImageView.

```
Glide.with(context).load("http://dummyimage.com/100x100.png/cc0000/ffffff"+busViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(c.getPhotourl(""))
                .into(busViewHolder.imageView);
```